# Robolectric ShadowActivity error

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I am starting to get familiar with Robolectric to create unit tests for Android applications.

My initial test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
private MainActivity mainActivity;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    mainActivity.onCreate(null);
}

@Test
public void sample() throws Exception {
    ShadowActivity act = Robolectric.shadowOf(mainActivity);
}

}
```

But `Robolectric.shadowOf(mainActivity)` gives me an error:

```
The type android.animation.Animator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Any ideas why? I have created simple android app with Android API Level 8. For the tests, I have Robolectric 2.1 jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changet from `shadowOf(mainActivity)` to `shadowOf_(mainActivity)` and everything works fine!